# How do I output the data from an object with dynamic properties in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

How do you output the data from an object  with dynamic properties. I have got an array of objects from an api call. This array contains one object named languages, they key value pair of this object are dynamic, so how to out put the data? I can output the name of the countries, capitals and flags but languages object which has dynamic properties I am not able to output it.

`

```
export default class CountryList extends React.Component {
   state = {
      countries: []
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all`)
         .then(res => {
            const countries = res.data;
            console.log(countries)
            this.setState({ countries });
         })

   }

   render() {
      this.state.countries.sort((a, b) => a.name.common > b.name.common ? 1 : -1,)
      return (
         < div >
            {
               this.state.countries.map((item, index) => (
                  <p key={index}> {item.name.common} {item.flag} {item.capital}  {item.name.official} </p>
               ))

            }
         </ div >
      )
   }
}
```

`

I tried but this didn't work to show the data from languages for each country

```
   this.state.countries.map((item, index) => {
         for (const iterator in item.languages) {
            console.log(iterator, item.languages[iterator]);
         }
      });
```

Comment: So what does `languages` supposed to look like? Any examples?

Comment: languages:
eng: "English"
hin: "Hindi"
tam: "Tamil"
This is how languages looks like, as you can see the key value pairs are for each country are different.

Comment: You can use `Object.values(item.languages)` to obtain an array of all values in the `language` object and use `map` to print them: `Object.values(item.languages).map(language => <li>{language}</li>)` (I am assuming you will display them in a unordered list, but you can use any other tag, obviously)

Comment: And where do I put Object.values(item.languages).map(language => <li>{language}</li>) I am already using map for names and flag

Comment: Nothing prevents you from having a map function nested into another map function

Comment: Can you please put the entire code?

Comment: By The way, instead of sorting the countries in the render function, wouldn't it be better to do it when you fetch the data? `const countries = res.data.sort(...)`

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As anticipated in the comments, you can use `Object.values()` (or `Object.entries()` if you want to use the language keys too) to get an array of all languages and `Array.prototype.map()` to display them.
You should end up with something like:

```js
export default class CountryList extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = {
        countries: []
      };
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all`).then(res => {
            const countries = res.data.sort((a, b) => (a.name.common > b.name.common ? 1 : -1));
            this.setState({ countries });
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.countries.length <= 0) return null;
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.countries.map((item, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <p>
                            {item.name.common} {item.flag} {item.capital} {item.name.official}
                        </p>
                        {item.languages && (<ul>
                          {Object.entries(item.languages).map(([lkey, language]) => (<li key={`${index}-${lkey}`}>{language}</li>))}
                        </ul>)}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Probably it is because at the first render countries is an empty array, therefore you should conditionally render it: `return this.state.countries.length > 0 ? (...) : null`. I am updating the answer to include that.

Comment: It gives still the same error.

Comment: Which line is generating the error?

Comment: the line from which the <ul> starts

Comment: It looks like `item.languages` is `undefined`; can you post the response of your API call? (`console.log(res.data)`);

Comment: This is what I get from (console.log(res.data))
[100 … 199]
100:
altSpellings: (5) ['IN', 'Bhārat', 'Republic of India', 'Bharat Ganrajya', 'இந்தியா']
area: 3287590
borders: (6) ['BGD', 'BTN', 'MMR', 'CHN', 'NPL', 'PAK']
capital: ['New Delhi']
capitalInfo: {latlng: Array(2)}
car: {signs: Array(1), side: 'left'}
cca2: "IN"
cca3: "IND"

Comment: That is only part of the response; please share at least one entire country (`console.log(res.data[0]);`)

Comment: Object
altSpellings: (2) ['AF', 'Afġānistān']
area: 652230
borders: (6) ['IRN', 'PAK', 'TKM', 'UZB', 'TJK', 'CHN']
capital: ['Kabul']
capitalInfo: {latlng: Array(2)}
car: {signs: Array(1), side: 'right'}
cca2: "AF"
cca3: "AFG"
ccn3: "004"
cioc: "AFG"
coatOfArms: {png: 'https://mainfacts.com/media/images/coats_of_arms/af.png', svg: 'https://mainfacts.com/media/images/coats_of_arms/af.svg'}
continents: ['Asia']
currencies: {AFN: {…}}
demonyms: {eng: {…}, fra: {…}}
fifa: "AFG"
flag: ""
flags: {png: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thu…

[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: If that is the entire object representing a country, it does not contain any `languages` key. Are you sure that is the entire object? What does `console.log(res.data[0].languages)` print?

Comment: I couldn't put the entire object as it is too long. console.log(res.data[0].languages) 
{prs: 'Dari', pus: 'Pashto', tuk: 'Turkmen'}
prs: "Dari"
pus: "Pashto"
tuk: "Turkmen"
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: Ok, the issue was that there is one country (Antarctica) which has no `languages` key. I updated the answer to handle that case too and I added a constructor to the class (which has nothing to do with the problem you were experiencing but I did nonetheless)

Comment: You're welcome... but you really should get used to debug your code as there won't always be someone doing it for you. ;)

Comment: You are right, I absolutely agree. How were you able to find it out?

Comment: Well, with the previous checks done via `console.log()` we already verified that the response from https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all was formatted as expected therefore the next logical step was to check whether _all_ countries did actually contain a `language` key. So I replicated the code here https://playcode.io/958209/ and tried to filter the countries array to find countries without `language` (`console.log(countries.filter(country => !country.languages))`). When it returned one result, the cause of the issue was found.

Answer (score 0):

Assume `countries` look like this:

```js
const countries = [
  {
    // other properties
    languages: [
      { eng: "English" },
      { hin: "Hindi" },
      // ...
    ]
  }
]
```

```js
for(const country of countries) {
  for(const language of country.languages) {
    // notice that this is a for... in loop instead of a for... of loop
    for(const langKey in language) { 
      console(langKey) // i.e. eng
      console.log(language[langKey]) // i.e. English
    }
  }
}
```

And if you need to render the languages as HTML elements:

```
countries.map(({ languages }) =>
  languages.map(language =>
    Object.entries(language).map(([langKey, lang]) => (
      <div>
        {/* i.e. eng */}
        {langKey}
        {/* i.e. English */}
        {lang}
      </div>
    ))
  )
)
```